# Moodle's get_string returns incorrect value

Tags: php, translation, moodle

I' creating a moodle local plugin
<s>I created a language file in `local/myplugin/lang/en/local_usercertlist.php`  with some keys</s>:
I created a language file in `local/myplugin/lang/en/local_myplugin.php`  with some keys:

```
<?php
$string['pluginname']="My Plug-in";
$string['testkey']="Test Val";
```

in `lib.php` I use `get_string` like this:

```
get_string('testkey','local_myplugin')
```

But I get `[[testkey]]` instead of `Test Val` !

why?  what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I just needed to increase plugin version & update moodle database;

Comment: You just need to purge cache after defining lang string. no need to update the plugin version.

Answer (score 1):

```
local/myplugin/lang/en/local_usercertlist.php
```

Should be

```
local/usercertlist/lang/en/local_usercertlist.php
```

and

```
get_string('testkey','local_myplugin')
```

should be

```
get_string('testkey','local_usercertlist')
```

Comment: It actually is, I just changed the plugin name and missed that one! the `pluginname` key is loaded correctly but the `testkey` is not! should I do soething after changing lang files?

Comment: Never mind, I updated the version file and it fixed; Thanks

Comment: You can purge the cache `/admin/purgecaches.php` - while developing though have this `$CFG->langstringcache = false;` in your `config.php`